# Service Worker With Stream Connection Reset

Tags: service-worker

The code below is getting executed, but I keep getting

> ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

```
addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  const stream = new ReadableStream({
  start(controller) {
    controller.enqueue('test')
    controller.close()
  }});
  event.waitUntil(event.respondWith(new Response(stream, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'}})))
});
```

If I replace the stream (in the response) with the same string inside the ReadableStream the response comes back correctly. I'm using the latest version of Chrome.

Is there something I'm missing?

This works below:

```
  event.waitUntil(
      event.respondWith(new Response('test', {headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/html; 
      charset=utf-8'}}))
  )
```

The service worker is definitely loading correctly and responding to the fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The text needs to be encoded first :)

```
controller.enqueue(new TextEncoder().encode('test'))
```